# tensorflow loaded model gives different predictions

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, sentiment-analysis, conv-neural-network

My code is to predict the sentiment of a sentence. I have trained a CNN model and saved it. When I loaded my model and try predict the sentiment of a sentence, I got different predictions for the same sentence. My code is as following, and the problem happens when I try to predict the sentene by calling the function predict_cnn_word2vec at the bottom:

```
import logging;
import numpy as np; 
import tensorflow as tf;
import sklearn as sk
import re; 
import json
import string;
import math
import os
from sklearn.metrics import recall_score, f1_score, precision_score;



class CNN(object):
def __init__(self,logger):
    self.logger = logger; 


def _weight_variable(self,shape):
    initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev = 0.1); 
    return tf.Variable(initial);

def _bias_variable(self,shape):
    initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape = shape); 
    return tf.Variable(initial);

def _conv2d(self,x, W, b, strides=1):
    # convolve and relu activation
    x = tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, strides, strides, 1], padding='SAME');
    x = tf.nn.bias_add(x, b);
    return tf.nn.relu(x);


def _maxpool(self,x, k=2):
    return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, k, k, 1], strides=[1, k, k, 1], padding='SAME');


def _init_CNN(self, sentence_width, sentence_height, dropout, learning_rate,n_class,is_training):
    self.logger.info("----------Initiating CNN---------");

    self.X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, sentence_height * sentence_width]);
    self.Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_class]); 

    x = tf.reshape(self.X, shape = [-1, sentence_height, sentence_width, 1]); 

    #1st convolution layer
    wc1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3, 3, 1, 5]));
    bc1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5]))
    stride1 = 2;
    pool1 = 2

    conv1 = self._conv2d(x, wc1, bc1,stride1);
    conv1 = self._maxpool(conv1, pool1);

    conv2 = conv1;

    pools = [2]#,2,2];
    strides = [2]#,1,1];
    last_channel = 5;


    first_size = self._get_first_connected_size(sentence_height,sentence_width, strides,pools,last_channel);

    # #1st fully connected layer
    wf1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([first_size, 32]));
    bf1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([32]));

    fc1 = tf.reshape(conv2, [-1, wf1.get_shape().as_list()[0]]);
    fc1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(fc1, wf1), bf1);
    fc1 = tf.nn.relu(fc1);
    fc1 = tf.nn.dropout(fc1, dropout)

    #dropout layer
    outw = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([32, n_class]));
    outb = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_class]));

    self.pred = tf.add(tf.matmul(fc1, outw), outb);
    self.y_p = tf.argmax(self.pred,1); 

    if is_training is False:
        return;


    # self.pred = self._predict(self.X,sentence_width, sentence_height, settings, dropout);
    self.cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(self.pred, self.Y)); 
    self.optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(self.cost);
    #accuracy
    self.y_t = tf.argmax(self.Y,1);
    self.accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(tf.equal(self.y_p, self.y_t), "float"))
    self.init = tf.initialize_all_variables(); 

def _get_first_connected_size(self,ih,iw, strides,pools,last_channel):
    i = 1;
    while i <= len(strides):
        iw = math.ceil(float(iw) / float(strides[i-1]));
        iw = math.ceil(float(iw) /pools[i-1]); 
        ih = math.ceil(float(ih) / float(strides[i-1]));
        ih = math.ceil(float(ih) /pools[i-1]);
        i = i + 1;
    first_connected_size = int(ih*iw*last_channel);
    return first_connected_size;

def train(self,data_provider,config):
    self._init_CNN(config.sentence_width, config.num_word, config.dropout, config.learning_rate,config.n_class,True);
    sess = tf.Session();
    sess.run(self.init);
    self.logger.info("Start Training!");
    #saver
    saver = tf.train.Saver(); 
    cur_max_accuracy = 0;
    cur_max_recall = 0;
    cur_max_precision = 0;

    if config.model_init_from is not None and os.path.exists(config.model_init_from):
        #restore model if exist
        saver.restore(sess, config.model_init_from);

    for epoch in range(config.epochs):
        data_provider.reset_batch_pointer();
        for i in range(data_provider.num_batches):
            batch_x, batch_y = data_provider.next_batch();
            accuracy_score,y_p,y_t, _, cost = sess.run([self.accuracy,self.y_p, self.y_t, self.optimizer, self.cost], feed_dict={self.X: batch_x, self.Y: batch_y});
            if i %10 == 0:
                self.logger.info("(%d/%d,%d epo) cost = %f, accuracy = %f,precision = %f, recall = %f, f_score = %f" % (i+epoch * data_provider.num_batches, data_provider.num_batches*config.epochs, epoch,cost,accuracy_score,precision_score(y_t, y_p),recall_score(y_t,y_p),f1_score(y_t,y_p)));
        self.accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(tf.equal(self.y_p, self.y_t), "float"))
        accuracy_score,y_p,y_t, _,cost = sess.run([self.accuracy,self.y_p, self.y_t, self.optimizer, self.cost], feed_dict={self.X: data_provider.get_test_X(), self.Y: data_provider.get_test_Y()})
        precision_score1 = precision_score(y_t, y_p);
        recall_score1 = recall_score(y_t,y_p);
        f1_score1 = f1_score(y_t,y_p);
        self.logger.info("#####(%d/%d epoch) cost = %f, accuracy = %f(max: %f), precision = %f(max: %f), recall = %f(max:%f), f_score = %f" % (epoch,config.epochs, cost,accuracy_score,cur_max_accuracy, precision_score1,cur_max_precision,recall_score1,cur_max_recall,f1_score1));

        save_loc = saver.save(sess, config.model_save_path);
        print("Model has been saved to: %s" % save_loc);
        cur_max_accuracy = accuracy_score;
        cur_max_recall = recall_score1;
        cur_max_precision = precision_score1;

def predict_cnn_word2vec(self, data_provider, config):
    if not os.path.exists(config.model_init_from):
        self.logger.info("model does not exist!");
        sys.exit(2);
    self._init_CNN(config.sentence_width, config.num_word, config.dropout, config.learning_rate,config.n_class,False)

    while True:
        sentence = input("Enter a sentence:");
        with tf.Session() as sess:
            saver = tf.train.Saver();
            saver.restore(sess, config.model_init_from);

            batch_x = np.empty((1, config.num_word*300));
            batch_x[0,:] = data_provider.get_sentence_vec(sentence,config);

            y_p = sess.run([self.y_p], feed_dict={self.X: batch_x});
            result = "positive" if y_p == [1] else "negative";
            self.logger.info("[%s] is %s" %(sentence,result));
```

When I called predict_cnn_word2vec() in my main function, I enter a while loop. For every sentence, the model would be reloaded to predict the sentiment of the sentence. For the first few loops, it gave the same results. But as I made more predictions, the result seems to change. The following is an example of my logs:

```
Enter a sentence:i adore him
2016-08-11 05:26:16,690 : INFO : [i adore him] is positive
Enter a sentence:i adore him
2016-08-11 05:26:19,662 : INFO : [i adore him] is positive
Enter a sentence:i adore him
2016-08-11 05:26:21,176 : INFO : [i adore him] is positive
Enter a sentence:i adore him
2016-08-11 05:26:22,568 : INFO : [i adore him] is positive
Enter a sentence:i adore him
2016-08-11 05:26:23,724 : INFO : [i adore him] is negative
Enter a sentence:i adore him
2016-08-11 05:26:25,791 : INFO : [i adore him] is negative
```

I have checked my data_provider which puts my sentence into a vector and it works perfectly as every time it returns the same sentence vector. So this problem should not be due to the input data. I wonder if every time tensorflow reloads the model, something in the model is reloaded correctly. Could anybody help me with this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not turning off dropout during inference!

Dropout causes a random fraction of the units in a layer to drop their activations to 0. This is a useful regularizer during training, but you don't want this behavior when validating or testing your model or running it in production.

Rather than initializing the network with a float dropout and continuing on your merry way, you need to make dropout a placeholder, just like your inputs and targets. During training, set this placeholder to something reasonable (eg 0.5) via the feed dict. During inference, set this placeholder to 1.0.

Comment: ooooh! I did not realize that. Thank you!